# How to use jQuery .ajax to my form's action

Tags: jquery

I changed my coding style for php and jQuery, but my Registration

```
$("#reg_form_company").bind("submit", function() {
    $.fancybox.showActivity();
    $.ajax({
            type     : "POST",
            cache    : false,
            url      : $(this).attr('action'),
            data     : $(this).serializeArray(),
            success  : function(data) {
                $(".printArea").empty().append(data).css('visibility','visible');
            }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Then this is my Form

```
<form id="reg_form_company" action="index.php?module=register&actionregister" method="post" >
      <input>[...]</input>
</form>
```

Then after clicking the "Submit" button, it doesn't work, I assume that somebody can help me to solve this problem, coz the $.ajax might confuse about POST(for inputs) and the GET(for the parameters of the "action" form)

I appreciate for your help, you can also modify the entire jQuery code if it's required.

Sorry guys for not including the #reg_form_company, and the fancybox

Comment: I took a second look at your code and I think I found your mistake. Take a look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041496/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-to-my-forms-action/10041588#10041588

Answer (score 33):

You need to do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/xSJTs/2/

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        url      : $(this).attr('action'),
        data     : $(this).serialize(),
        success  : function(data) {
            $(".printArea").empty().append(data).css('visibility','visible');
        }
    });

});
```

You have to use `serialize()` instead of `serializeArray()`. `serializeArray()` creates a JavaScript-object, `serialize()` creates a query-string.

Serialize: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

SerializeArray: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Basically you wait until the form is submitted and then you interrupt it (`e.preventDefault();`).

Comment: NB : The button you are using to trigger the event that causes the submit of the form via ajax post should not be of type **submit**! Else this will always fail.

Answer (score 5):

You must intercept the click/submit event for your form and refer the form as shown bellow:

```
 $("#myForm").submit(function(){
    var $form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
     type     : "POST",
     cache    : false,
     url      : $form.attr('action'),
     data     : $form.serializeArray(),
     success  : function(data) {
         $(".printArea").empty().append(data).css('visibility','visible');
     }
    });
 })
```

And add an id to your form like:

```
<form id="myForm" action="index.php?module=register&actionregister" method="post" >
      <input>[...]</input>
</form>
```

Comment: yah sir, I already have the id, but the the $.ajax cant reach the server side code, while If I turned off the jQuery, the php is working...

Answer (score 2):

### File input working ajax

Hi,
the other answers **has not worked** for me since I needed to pass **files** inputs and thoses cannot be "serialized".

The good way is to pass it via `FormData` and disable `processData`:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        cache      : false,
        url        : $(this).attr('action'),
        data       : formData,
        success    : (data) => console.log('Data returned from server => ', data),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you must refere your form instead of `$(this)`

give your form an id or class ex :

```
<form action="index.php?module=register&actionregister" method="post" id="MyForm">
      <input>[...]</input>
</form>
```

and in JQuery :

```
$.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        url      : $('#MyForm').attr('action'),
        data     : $('#MyForm').serializeArray(),
        success  : function(data) {
            $(".printArea").empty().append(data).css('visibility','visible');
        }
});
```

Comment: yah sir, I already have the id, but the the $.ajax cant reach the server side code, while If I turned off the jQuery, the php is working...

Answer (score 0):

```
    //This is still showing the cgi output of my script in the browser
 $('#myForm').submit(function()){
                 $('#myForm').preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type     : "POST",
            cache    : false,
            url      : $('#myForm').attr('action'),
            data     : $('#myForm').serialize(),
            success  : function(data) {
                $(".printArea").empty().append(data).css('visibility','visible');
            };

    <form id = "myForm" action="cgi-bin/matt/matt-test.cgi?module=register&actionregister" method ="post">
```